# How can I disable line numbers on empty lines?

Tags: whitespace, line-numbers, linum-mode

I find it easier to visualize double line breaks if there's actually blank space between paragraphs. I never need to see the line number of a blank line, but I do really like seeing a line number when there is text there.

How can I do this easily? (I'm using more or less the default Doom Emacs configuration as of August 2020).

Comment: As of Emacs 26, there are built-in line numbers called `display-line-numbers-mode`, which cannot be customized to eliminate line numbers on empty lines before end of the buffer.  The deprecated Lisp versions of line numbers such as `linum.el` and `nlinum.el` could most certainly be tweaked as you desire, but as mentioned, they are deprecated.  Because the question does not specify what implementation of line numbers are at issue, other than at tag referring to the Lisp version, it would behoove you to edit your question accordingly.  As to the Lisp version, your tweak would affect performance.

Comment: Edited. Please don't ask whether something is "reasonable" etc. That risks getting the question deleted as being primarily opinion-based. The Q&A here should be specific, and generally "how-to". Thx.